# Google Maps Store Locator

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, phpmyadmin

I am fairly new to Google maps API v3. I followed the tutorial on how to make a store locator and everything worked smoothly. However, I am not familiar with phpMyAdmin and I cannot think of how I can make, instead of searching the store it searches a number of stores inventories and returns the store with that item in stock.

My code is as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"

            type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[

    var map;

    var markers = [];

    var infoWindow;

    var locationSelect;



    function load() {

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),

        zoom: 4,

        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',

        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}

      });

      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



      locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");

      locationSelect.onchange = function() {

        var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;

        if (markerNum != "none"){

          google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');

        }

      };

   }



   function searchLocations() {

     var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;

     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

     geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {

       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);

       } else {

         alert(address + ' not found');

       }

     });

   }



   function clearLocations() {

     infoWindow.close();

     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

       markers[i].setMap(null);

     }

     markers.length = 0;



     locationSelect.innerHTML = "";

     var option = document.createElement("option");

     option.value = "none";

     option.innerHTML = "See all results:";

     locationSelect.appendChild(option);

   }



   function searchLocationsNear(center) {

     clearLocations(); 



     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;

     var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;

     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {

       var xml = parseXml(data);

       var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {

         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");

         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");

         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));

         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(

              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),

              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));



         createOption(name, distance, i);

         createMarker(latlng, name, address);

         bounds.extend(latlng);

       }

       map.fitBounds(bounds);

       locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";

       locationSelect.onchange = function() {

         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;

         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');

       };

      });

    }



    function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {

      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        map: map,

        position: latlng

      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        infoWindow.setContent(html);

        infoWindow.open(map, marker);

      });

      markers.push(marker);

    }



    function createOption(name, distance, num) {

      var option = document.createElement("option");

      option.value = num;

      option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";

      locationSelect.appendChild(option);

    }



    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {

      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?

          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :

          new XMLHttpRequest;



      request.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (request.readyState == 4) {

          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;

          callback(request.responseText, request.status);

        }

      };



      request.open('GET', url, true);

      request.send(null);

    }



    function parseXml(str) {

      if (window.ActiveXObject) {

        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');

        doc.loadXML(str);

        return doc;

      } else if (window.DOMParser) {

        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');

      }

    }



    function doNothing() {}



    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>



  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="load()"> 

    <div>

     <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="10"/>

    <select id="radiusSelect">

      <option value="3" selected>3mi</option>

      <option value="5">5mi</option>

      <option value="10">10mi</option>

      <option value="25">25mi</option>

    </select>



    <input type="button" onclick="searchLocations();" value="Search"/>



    </div>

    <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width:500;visibility:hidden"></select></div>

    <div id="map" style="width: 500; height: 500"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

And

```
<?php  
require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 3",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the name of the field is that contains the inventory info?  Or, if you can shows us your database schema that would be best.

Comment: name, address, lat, lng

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/articles/phpsqlsearch/phpsqlsearch_data.csv

Comment: I have not figured out how to link each store to an inventory

Comment: You need to have a field or a linked-table (primary key and foreign key) that includes info for the inventory.  Then you can modify the SQL query to search based on proximity AND inventory.  Have you created your own database?  Sounds like you need to come up to speed on SQL...

Comment: I have created a database, and set an auto-increased primary key for the table that includes the stores. I just cannot imagine how I would make a table for the inventory. Would i create a table with id, storeid, product, and productType ? 

then add all of the products. but from there how do I link one store in the other table to a separate inventory list.

Comment: Yes.  Then you would use a join in your query (*though a View is likely better) to query against the store inventory.  So you would check to see that inventory is > 0.  Your query would include something like FROM markers WHERE (<your join query> and <inventory field> > 0) AND HAVING distance...

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew I was forgetting something. I completely disregarded joining the tables in the query

Comment: Moving my comment to the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a join in your query (though a View is likely better) to query against the store inventory. So you would check to see that inventory is > 0. Your query would include something like `FROM markers WHERE (`*[your join query]* `and` *[inventory field]* `> 0) AND HAVING distance`...